# HTML5 drag and drop --place a counter on HTML form that will count number of drags

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have 8 list items on a web page floated towards the left of the page and a dustbin item towards the right of the page. When I drag each of the item into the dustbin, the dustbin eats away the item. I already have the code for that. Now what I need is to place a counter on my web page that will count the number of drags into the dustbin. Please help! Below is my complete HTML and javscript code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>
<title>HTML5 Drag and drop demonstration</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 50px;
  font-family: helvetica, arial;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
/* padding: 10px;*/
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  /*border: 3px dashed #999;*/
  border: 5px solid #000;
 /* background: #eee;*/
  background:#FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select:none;
/* -webkit-user-drag: element;*/
  -khtml-user-drag: element;
  display: block;;
}

*:-khtml-drag {
  background-color: rgba(238,238,238, 0.5);
}

a:hover:after {
 /* content: ' (drag me)';*/
 content: ' (throw me!)';
}

li.over {
  border-color: #333;
  background: #ccc;
}

#bin {
  background: url(images/dustbinnew1.jpg) top right no-repeat;
  height: 250px;
  width: 166px;
  float:right;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

#bin.over {
  background: url(images/dustbinnew2.jpg)  repeat;
}

#bin p {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 166px;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #000 2px 2px 2px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="bin"></div>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="one" href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="two">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="three">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="four">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="five">five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="six">six</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="seven">seven</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="eight">eight</a></li>
  </ul>
  <script src="h5utils.js"></script>
  <script>


 var eat = ['yum!', 'gulp', 'burp!', 'nom'];
var yum = document.createElement('p');
  var msie = /*@cc_on!@*/0;
 yum.style.opacity = 1;

  var links = document.querySelectorAll('li > a'), el = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    el = links[i];

    // even required? Spec says yes, browsers say no.
    el.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');

    addEvent(el, 'dragstart', function (e) {
      e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id); // set *something* required otherwise doesn't work
    });
  }

  var bin = document.querySelector('#bin');

  addEvent(bin, 'dragover', function (e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); // allows us to drop
    this.className = 'over';
    return false;
  });

  addEvent(bin, 'dragleave', function () {
    this.className = '';
  });

  addEvent(bin, 'drop', function (e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting...why???

    var el = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));

    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);

    // stupid nom text + fade effect
    bin.className = '';
    yum.innerHTML = eat[parseInt(Math.random() * eat.length)];

    var y = yum.cloneNode(true);
    bin.appendChild(y);

    setTimeout(function () {
      var t = setInterval(function () {
        if (y.style.opacity <= 0) {
          if (msie) { // don't bother with the animation
            y.style.display = 'none';
          }
          clearInterval(t);
        } else {
          y.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        }
      }, 50);
    }, 250);

    return false;
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my javascript file h5utils.js:
// JavaScript Document

```
var addEvent = (function () {
  if (document.addEventListener) {
    return function (el, type, fn) {
      if (el && el.nodeName || el === window) {
        el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
      } else if (el && el.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
          addEvent(el[i], type, fn);
        }
      }
    };
  } else {
    return function (el, type, fn) {
      if (el && el.nodeName || el === window) {
        el.attachEvent('on' + type, function () { return fn.call(el, window.event); });
      } else if (el && el.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
          addEvent(el[i], type, fn);
        }
      }
    };
  }
})();

(function () {

var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.id = "view-source"

// private scope to avoid conflicts with demos
addEvent(window, 'click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.hash == '#view-source') {
    // event.preventDefault();
    if (!document.getElementById('view-source')) {
      // pre.innerHTML = ('<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n' + document.documentElement.innerHTML + '\n</html>').replace(/[<>]/g, function (m) { return {'<':'&lt;','>':'&gt;'}[m]});
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      // original source - rather than rendered source
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          pre.innerHTML = this.responseText.replace(/[<>]/g, function (m) { return {'<':'&lt;','>':'&gt;'}[m]});
          prettyPrint();
        }
      };

      document.body.appendChild(pre);
      // really need to be sync? - I like to think so
      xhr.open("GET", window.location, true);
      xhr.send();
    }
    document.body.className = 'view-source';

    var sourceTimer = setInterval(function () {
      if (window.location.hash != '#view-source') {
        clearInterval(sourceTimer);
        document.body.className = '';
      }
    }, 200);
  }
});



})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need add your code to:

```
var countDrops = 0;
window.onload = function(){

//your code

}
```

and on drop event

```
  addEvent(bin, 'drop', function (e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting...why???

    /* CONTADOR */
    countDrops++;
    alert(countDrops);
```

the error was because you tried assigning events to the list of links before the elements (divs, links, etc.) were loaded.

with window.onload does is wait for all the HTML is ready and then assigns the events.

```
var countDrops = 0;

window.onload = function(){
 var eat = ['yum!', 'gulp', 'burp!', 'nom'];
var yum = document.createElement('p');
  var msie = /*@cc_on!@*/0;
 yum.style.opacity = 1;

  var links = document.querySelectorAll('li > a'), el = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    el = links[i];

    // even required? Spec says yes, browsers say no.
    el.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');

    addEvent(el, 'dragstart', function (e) {
      e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id); // set *something* required otherwise doesn't work
    });
  }

  var bin = document.querySelector('#bin');

  addEvent(bin, 'dragover', function (e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); // allows us to drop
    this.className = 'over';
    return false;
  });

  addEvent(bin, 'dragleave', function () {
    this.className = '';
  });

  addEvent(bin, 'drop', function (e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting...why???

    /* CONTADOR */
    countDrops++;
    alert(countDrops);


    var el = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));

    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);

    // stupid nom text + fade effect
    bin.className = '';
    yum.innerHTML = eat[parseInt(Math.random() * eat.length)];

    var y = yum.cloneNode(true);
    bin.appendChild(y);

    setTimeout(function () {
      var t = setInterval(function () {
        if (y.style.opacity <= 0) {
          if (msie) { // don't bother with the animation
            y.style.display = 'none';
          }
          clearInterval(t);
        } else {
          y.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        }
      }, 50);
    }, 250);

    return false;
  });


  }
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear please...where do I put the           var countDrops = 0;
window.onload = function(){                                           }