# How to get data at runtime in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using drag and drop event to drag some images in a div. I want to count the number of objects/images being dropped at runtime and limit the number of images in that div. How can I do this using jquery?

Following is the code for dropping the images:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    /*
    var countDrv = $("[name=Driver]").val;
    for (i = 0; i < countDrv.length) {
        if (countDrv > 2) {
            alert("Drivers should not be more than two");
        }
    }
    */
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Code is working only for dropping images but not for counting images. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: ajax is solution for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19946061/4229270

Comment: I am using only jquery for that. Can we do this using only jquery?

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya - how is AJAX going to help?

Comment: @MuhammadShahid `I am using only jquery` - where? I see no jquery in the 6 lines you posted

Comment: @MuhammadShahid - do you know how to get the count? hint: it's `ev.dataTransfer.items.length`

Comment: @Jaromanda X Sorry for my mistake I meant to say I have to use jquery only for this purpose,

Comment: are you saying you are not allowed to use javascript? hint: jquery is a library, written in javascript. The number of items dropped is a property of the event, which is not accessible using "only jquery" - because jquery has no special jquery methods to access properties that are accessible to regular javascript. Also, the code you presented has no jquery, so why in the gods names would you say you can only use jquery for the solution?

Comment: I meant to say only javascript and jquery not ajax.

Comment: I see, yeah, not sure why anyone would think AJAX has anything to do with this question

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/92r4sLcL/

```js
 allowDrop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

 drag = function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

 drop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    console.log(document.getElementById('div1').childNodes.length);
}
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
<img id="drag2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

Here in the solution, I have 2 images which can be dropped into the above container.

Once you drop an image, you will get the number of `childNodes` in the drop zone (I've consoled it in the `browser console`).

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below which limits drag and drop.

```
 allowDrop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

 drag = function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

 drop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var limit = 4;
    //document.getElementById(ev.target.id).childNodes.length contains the count/no.of images
    if(document.getElementById(ev.target.id).childNodes.length < limit){
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));    
    }else{ 
      alert('you cannot drop images here. maximum limit reached..');
      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks once again. I accept it. I have voted for your answer.